# How can I combine ColReorderWithResize with HTML5 buttons on Datatables javascript

Tags: javascript, button, datatables, header, resize

I am using a databales javascript in my web site, with html5 buttons

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html , is working fine, but now I want to allow resize on fly the columns of the datatables , so I found this http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/

But the problem now is, I don´t know how to use both together.

```
myApp.table = $('#TableId').DataTable(
{
    rowReorder: { update: false },
    columnDefs: [
        { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] },
        { "className": "text-left custom-middle-align", "targets": [0, 1, 2] },
        { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 0 },
        { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
    ],
    autoWidth: false,
    sDom: "Rlfrtip", //--> here is the code to resize columns

    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp', // here the code to see the buttons
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
```

In fact I don´t understand well the code used by datatables Rlfrtip and B>ltfgitp

Thanks in advance.

Jolynice